# How to separate texts in HTML using CSS

Tags: html, css

If you go to khan academy you'll see the Login/Signup and subjects on different sides, also the khanacademy logo in the center.

I've been trying to make my website the same but always something wrong

```css
    body{
 font-family: 'Comfortaa', cursive;
    }
    .header{
     border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
     padding: 10px 0px;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
    }
    .header a{
     color: #333;
     text-decoration: none;
     margin: 250px;
    }
    .header a:hover{
     color: #EEEEEE;
    }
```

```html
 <div class="header">
  <a href="/" class="a1">Test</a>
  <a href="logsign.php" class="a2">Login / Signup</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way Khan Academy does it is with 3 container elements. Then they justify the content inside of those separate elements. Here I'm doing without flexbox and just using floats and clearfix.

## HTML

```
<header>
    <div class="header_left"></div>
    <div class="header_center"></div>
    <div class="header_right"></div>
</header>
```

## CSS

```
header:after{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    clear:both;
}

header > div{
    float:left;
}

.header_left{
    width:40%;
    text-align:left;
}

.header_center{
    width:20%;
    text-align:center;
}

.header_right{
    width:40%;
    text-align:right;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, i modified the header_right to 20% width, but when i edit the header_left to 20% width nothing changes, what i mean is, i didn't want both ends to be stuck to the browser page.

Comment: Actually I don't understand what you're looking for. If you want the header to be a fixed width, I recommend adding a `max-width` to the `header`. Then the children can be contained inside the header and not look like they are stuck to the sides of the page.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this easily using `display: flex; justify-content: space-between;`

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <a href="/" class="a1">Test</a>
    <a href="logsign.php" class="a2">Login / Signup</a>
 </div>
```

Using the same technique, you can easily add a logo in the middle.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 960px;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <a href="/" class="a1">Test</a>
    <a href="/">Logo</a>
    <a href="logsign.php" class="a2">Login / Signup</a>
 </div>
```

Comment: I've tried this but it's simply moving the TEST and LOGIN to the center of the screen

Comment: @ChristepherArakelian if you need help with your code, you need to create a verifiable demo of the problem http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve